# How to Copy a file that was read from a list

Tags: vbscript, copy, wsh

Hello guys I have an issue or issues with my code above
I'm trying to get "sExtension" to be search in a different folder other that the one I'm using to save my script since this script will be use as a Startup Script on many computers

(It works only if I run the script in the same folder "sExtension", "ExtAssign.txt" and sComputername are otherwise it wont find the path)

This is what it should do
Read a file called "ExtAssign.txt" (There is a full list of computer names in that file) and if it find the computer name on that file then it should copy a file with the with the extension number assigned to that computer name from a file server to "C:\" Drive

For this example I'm trying to do this locally, If I can make it then I'll try it from my File Server

```
Set objFSO    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oFso       = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fso        = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oShell     = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set oShellEnv  = oShell.Environment("Process")
Set folder     = Fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Test\Extensions\")
Set wshshell   = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set ObjEnv     = WshShell.Environment("Process")
Set objFso     = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Scomputername  = ObjEnv("COMPUTERNAME")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objWShell = wScript.createObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim strFile
'File to scan
strFile = "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Test\Extensions\Extassign\ExtAssign.txt"

Dim strPattern
'Look for computer name in file
strPattern = scomputername

Set objFso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
 Dim strLine
    'Read each line and store it in strLine
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    'If the line matches the computer name, save the line to ExtArray
    If InStr(strLine,strPattern)>0 Then
        Dim ExtArray
        'Split the line and separate the extension
        ExtArray = Split(strLine,"|", -1, 1)
    Dim sExtension
        'Save the extension to sExtension
        sExtension=ExtArray(1)
    End If
Loop
'If the sExtension is empty, computer was not found, send message and terminate script.
If sExtension="" Then
WScript.Echo "ERROR: Computer "& scomputername &" not found in Extension Assignment List, so no extension has been set.  Avaya will not be launched.  Please contact your IT department for assistance."
Else
    'If the sExtension contains a number, Copy that file to C:\ and rename it to Config.xml
    fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Test\Extensions\ "& sExtension &"", "C:\Config.xml", True
End If
```

at the end it if it finds the file sExtension it will rename it to Config.xml but it wont do it unless I run the script in the same folder sExtension and sComputername.

I get File not found error

Thank you in advance and Happy new year!

Comment: Is this Visual Basic? You might want to tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is most likely this line:

```
fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Test\Extensions\ "& sExtension &"", "C:\Config.xml", True
```

There is a trailing space after the last backslash in the path, so you're creating a path

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Test\Extensions\ 12345
                                       ^
```

when you actually want a path

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Test\Extensions\12345
```

---

On a more general note: why are you creating 7(!) `FileSystemObject` instances (replacing one of them three times on top of that)? And 3(!) `WScript.Shell` instances? You don't even use most of them, not to mention that you don't need the `Shell` object in the first place. You only use it for determining the computer name, which could be done just fine using the `WScript.Network` object (that you don't use at all).

Also, *please* don't ever use comments like this:

```
'Read each line and store it in strLine
strLine = objFile.ReadLine
```

It's quite obvious that you read each line and assign it to the variable `strLine`. Comments shouldn't rephrase *what* you're doing (the code already does that, at least when you're using speaking variable and function names), but *why* you're doing it, i.e. what the purpose of a particular code section is.

Your code could be reduced to something as simple as this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

computername = net.ComputerName
foldername   = "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Test\Extensions"
filename     = fso.BuildPath(foldername, "Extassign\ExtAssign.txt")

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  line = f.ReadLine
  If InStr(line, computername) > 0 Then
    arr = Split(line, "|", -1, 1)
    If UBound(arr) >= 1 Then extension = arr(1)
  End If
Loop
f.Close

If IsEmpty(extension) Then
  WScript.Echo "ERROR: Computer "& computername &" not found in ..."
Else
  fso.CopyFile fso.BuildPath(foldername, extension), "C:\Config.xml", True
End If
```